# Does Array.sort() implements comparable ? When I looked at the Array Class it doesn't ,so How does the sort work here?

Tags: java, comparable

How sorting is done here as I can see `Arrays` class doesn't implement `Comparable`.

```
        //Add values to Array
        int arrayname[]=new int[3];
        arrayname[0]=40;
        arrayname[1]=10;
        arrayname[2]=35;
            
        //Sort the elements
        Arrays.sort(arrayname);
            
        //Display values  
        System.out.println("Values in Array After Sorting:");
        for(int i=0;i<arrayname.length;i++){
            System.out.print(arrayname[i]+", ");
        }
```

Comment: Just look at the source code of ```Arrays.sort```.  Why ```Arrays``` need to implement  ```Comparator```

Comment: I understood in such a way that compareTo() method of the comparable interface can be used to sort arrays and collections . Say if I use Collections.sort() it will internally call compareTo method so if I call Arrays.sort I was under the assumption that the same method is called internally

Answer (score 1):

It does not have to.
It uses the type's `compareTo` method. That means in the case of **objects** you need to implement the `Comparable<T>` interface.

See [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object%5B%5D))

For primitive types, they have a natural ordering already.

You can [also pass a lambda or a method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator)) to have a custom sorting.

Comment: Raildex  -

Sorts the specified array of objects into ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements. 
It also says  "All elements in the array must implement the Comparable interface."

Comment: @SreekumarSachidanandan what is your problem? What do you don't understand?

Comment: All elements in the array must implement the Comparable interface .
Elements which I passed are primitives

Comment: @SreekumarSachidanandan you are not calling `Arrays.sort(Object[])`, you are calling `Arrays.sort(int[])` which either boxes `int` to `Integer` (which implements `Comparable<Integer>`) or it simply uses natural integer ordering for sort

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the `Arrays.sort()` code, it uses a class named `ComparableTimSort` internally. This class has a method `ComparableTimSort.binarySort(Object[] a, int lo, int hi, int start)`, which actually expects that the elements in parameter `a` be `Comparable`.

Since `Arrays.sort()` is a `static` method, a utility method, `Arrays` doesn't directly implement `Comparable`. It is the elements in the array passed to it that need to be `Comparable`.

Comment: Sree Kumar -
arrayname[0]=40; 
so you mean when I assign the primitive on right hand side its converted to Wrapper Class Integer else how the elements which I passed became comparable

Comment: Should be so, yes. Have you tried? As I mentioned, I just went through the code and explained. (I assume you didn't mean passing an `int[]` for which there is an overloaded method.)

Comment: public static void sort(int[] a)